# setContentView removes other components on my activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I am currently trying to add a line between two points on my screen, the problem occurs when I apply the content view and it removes previous contents and only applies the line. Currently I have a image, a checkbox, and a textview in my activity's .xml file, code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/mapau" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pointer"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pointer"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:duplicateParentState="false"
        android:text="Disponible"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteCheck"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I am using a java class to add said line and calling it in my main code inside my `onStart` `protected` `void`:

```
drawView = new DrawView(this);
setContentView(drawView);
```

The java class I am using:

```
package com.example.vitto.udlc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(200, 0, 0, 200, paint);
    }

}
```

I am fairly new to android studio so I am obviously over looking something, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: setContentView method to set view for certain activity that mean the view will appeared will be  DrawView only

Comment: setContentView sets the entire layout for that activity, It does not act like an append or overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think that you have to use:

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); //all this code in your activity
DrawView drawView= new DrawView(this);
ViewGroup frameLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content);

drawView.setLayoutParams(new 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
frameLayout.addView(drawView);
```

In this way you set your layout on background and then you add the lines over the layout.

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you very much. Let me see if i got this right, with this code we make a new relative layout and set the drawView on the new layout instead of the previous layout?

Comment: @VittoRusso see the answer. I updated it for your framelayout

Answer (score 0):

You're likely not "removing" the old components, the more likely cause of your problem is that the canvas takes up the whole screen, and when you draw to it, it covers up everything behind it.

Open the hierarchy viewer and see if the canvas does or doesn't cover the old elements, if it does, you now know the root of your issue. Here's a link for how to use the hierarchy viewer: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html

What happens when the canvas "onDraw" method gets called, is it will generate the canvas, and then draw to it every time the onDraw method gets called, which would bring it to the front, so unless you were somehow telling the other ui elements to be brought to the front, they would get obscured.

You could also check if the canvas obscures it by just making the canvas transparent, try this code in the onDraw method:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY);
```